# Consecutive user inputs in C

Tags: c, input, whitespace, scanf, fgets

In my program, I have a function that looks something like this

```
char a[100];
char b[100];
char d[100];

int c;

scanf("%[^\n]%*c", a);
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", b);
scanf("%d", &c);
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", d);
```

When I run the function and give it inputs, the out put is

```
   whatever the first input was
   whatever the second input was
   12345
   ��� //it skips this line and doesn't let me enter anything here
```

Running the function twice instead of once

```
   whatever the first input was  
   whatever the second input was
   12345
   ��� //skipped


   whatever the first input was //skipped
   whatever the second input was //skipped
   9876 //not skipped
   ��� //skipped
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &c);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &c);` or `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", d);` --> `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", d);`

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something small like that.

Comment: `"%[^\n]%*c"` fails to scan in anything when the first `char` is `'\n'`.  In the long run, simple do not use `scanf()`.  1) Use `fgets()` and then parse the input. 2) check the return value of input functions.